# Jython exception, <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> в Grinder

Tags: java, нагрузочное-тестирование, jython

При помощи [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) делаю нагрузочное тестирование. Для проверки подключения `jar`'ника в `jython` скрипт создал простой `java` файл - `HelloWorld.java`:

```
package my;

public class HelloWorld {
    public String HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello, world";
    }
}
```

Далее преобразовываю `java` файл в `jar`'ник:

```
user@server: javac HelloWorld.java
user@server: jar cvf helloworld.jar HelloWorld.class
added manifest
adding: HelloWorld.class(in = 292) (out= 211)(deflated 27%)
```

Как пишут в [официальной документации](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/properties.html), для того, чтобы тестовый скрипт мог увидеть `java` классы, надо прописать в файле `grinder.properties` прописать настройку `grinder.jvm.classpath`:

> Use to adjust the classpath used for the worker process JVMs. Anything specified here will be prepended to the classpath used to start the Grinder processes.

```
grinder.jvm.classpath = /path/to/helloworld.jar
```

И в самом начале `jython` скрипта прописываю:

```
from my import HelloWorld
```

При запуске `worker`'а выскакивает ошибка:

```
2015-12-09 11:03:50,305 ERROR testID-0: aborting process - Jython exception, <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named my [initialising test script]
net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named my
    from my.HelloWorld import HelloWorld
    File "~/Projects/alipay/grinder/./testID.local-file-store/current/test.py", line 5, in <module>
```

Можете подсказать, в чем дело?

Comment: Не знаю что такое grinder, но оно же вам говорит "No module named my", т.е. "my" ему не нравится. Проверьте синтаксис импорта.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov синтаксис брал из оф. доки, а так же из [туториала от  Kjetil Valle](http://kjetilvalle.com/posts/java-grinder-tests.html)

Comment: @MichaelPak в `grinder.jvm.classpath` используете относительный путь до jar?

Comment: @PavelParshin, нет, использую абсолютный путь

Comment: Тогда могу предположить, что стоит указать относительный путь до jar, как в данном [примере](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/scripts.html#cwd)

Comment: @PavelParshin пробовал и относительный, и абсолютный путь.

Comment: Класс упакован в jar? Пути к jar прописаны правильно? Большие маленькие буквы различаются. Не видит он "модуль" my. Нет ли какого-нибудь специального требования, чтобы имя jar файла соответствовало имени "модуля" (пакета)? Пробовали подключать какие-нибудь стандартные классы из JVM?

Comment: Ну, и поскольку я вижу у вас Linux - /path/to/helloworld.jar с точкой вначале или без? Вы знаете разницу, что "/" в Linux это корневой каталог, типа "C:" в Windows, а "./" - это каталог относительно текущего?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov, класс упакован в jar, пути к jar прописаны правильно, юзал `pwd` для верности. Требования к названию jar не видел. Стандартные классы надо попробовать. У меня OS X, но да, я знаю различия между `/` и `./`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Настроил тестовый пример на Windows. Все заработало.

**grinder.properties**

```
grinder.processes=1
grinder.threads=1
grinder.runs=0
grinder.script=script.py
grinder.jvm.classpath=lib/hello.jar
grinder.jvm.arguments = -Dpython.home=C:/projects/other/grinder/jython -Dpython.cachedir=C:/projects/other/grinder/tmp
grinder.numberOfOldLogs=100
grinder.hostID=localhost
grinder.consoleHost=127.0.0.1
grinder.consolePort=6372
grinder.useConsole=true
grinder.reportToConsole.interval=500
grinder.initialSleepTime=0
grinder.sleepTimeFactor=1
grinder.sleepTimeVariation=0.1
grinder.logProcessStreams=true
grinder.reportTimesToConsole=true
grinder.debug.singleprocess=false
grinder.useNanoTime=false
```

**Hello.java**

```
package my.java;

public class Hello {
    public String log() {
        return "Hello, world, from Java";
    }
}
```

**script.py**

```
from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
from net.grinder.script import Test

# A shorter alias for the grinder.logger.info() method.
log = grinder.logger.info

# Create a Test with a test number and a description. The test will be
# automatically registered with The Grinder console if you are using
# it.
test1 = Test(1, "Log method")

# Instrument the info() method with our Test.
test1.record(log)

from my.java import Hello

# A TestRunner instance is created for each thread. It can be used to
# store thread-specific data.
class TestRunner:

    def __init__(self):
        self.runner = Hello()

    # This method is called for every run.
    def __call__(self):
        log(self.runner.log())
```

Также настроил три cmd-файла согласно [руководству](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/getting-started.html) для запуска и установки среды.

**Файловая структура:**

```
grinder
--jython
--lib
----grinder-3.11
----hello.jar
--tmp
--grinder.properties
--script.py
```

**Также проверьте корректность создания jar**.

В моем примере:

1. `javac my\java\Hello.java` (обратите внимание на соответствие файловой структуры с именем пакета. В вашем случае это `javac my\HelloWorld.java`).
2. `jar cvf hello.jar my\java\Hello.class`.

Comment: Да, проблема была в том, что не правильно собрал `jar`'ку. Спасибо большое!